# Is there a GPO setting to enable/disable "show autocomplete suggestions" in word 2003?

Tags: group-policy

Searched through all the GPO settings a few times and can't see anything for this setting... Does anyone know if this can be done?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is in the Administrative Template files (get those [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/office-2003-resource-kit/redir/XT010239219.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA010238019))

Browse to:

> Microsoft Word 2003\"Tools | AutoCorrect Options..."\AutoText "Show Autocomplete suggestions"

Comment: Hmmm... I don't see: AutoText "Show Autocomplete suggestions".
The ADM has been there for a while... perhaps I need to install the latest ADM?

Comment: I would try it.  The link above in my answer is the SP3 version.